# getting content on the right line regardless of browser resolution with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following layout:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="category">
      <div class="label">Label1: </div><div class="content">Content1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="category">
      <div class="label">Label2: </div><div class="content">Content2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="category">
      <div class="label">Label3: </div><div class="content">Content3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="category">
      <div class="label">Label4: </div><div class="content">Content4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to have each row on its own row if it can fit; however, if the window is resized or resolution is too low, I want it to go to a new line at each category.  As it stands, when there is not enough space, it is just totally wrecking the formatting.  My CSS is as follows:

```
.container {
    width: 600px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 4px;
}
.row {
    clear: both;
}
.category {
    width: 300px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.left {
    float: left;
}
.right {
    float: right;
}
.label {
    float: left;
}
.content {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

My problem is twofold.  One: the container does not expand to the vertical size of the contents.  Two: If is resize the container width down, it messes the whole thing up, rather than moving to the next line as desired.  In the actual project, the container width is assigned as a % of the body width, which obviously varies depending on the size of the window, so it needs to work on other screens.

https://jsfiddle.net/pja7meLd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background color isn't extending to match the height because you need to clear the floats. But I would use flexbox on those rows, and within the category elements, then you have more control over the layout and no need to clear floats.

```css
.container {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.category {
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="category ">
      <div class="label">Label1:&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="content">Content1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="category ">
      <div class="label">Label2:&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="content">Content2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="category ">
      <div class="label">Label3:&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="content">Content3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="category ">
      <div class="label">Label4:&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="content">Content4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the desired behavior by adding to container and changing .right as follows:

```
.container {
  /* (same as above plus the following line) */
  position: absolute;
}
.right {
  float: left;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pja7meLd/1/